# How to create html from a two dimensional array?

Tags: javascript

My array has the pairs of child and parent elements . The first element of each `subarray` is a child , the second is the parent

```
var myArray = [['activity', 'none'] , 
               ['movies', 'activity'],
               ['theater','activity'],
               ['drama', 'movies'],
               ['comedy', 'movies'],    
               ['puppet', 'theater'], 
                    . . 
               ];
```

I need to create the following HTML dynamically:

```
<div id='activity'>activity

     <div id='movies'>movies
               <div id='drama'>drama</div>
               <div id='comedy'>comedy</div>  
     </div>

     <div id='theater'>
               <div id='puppet'>puppet</div>
     </div>

</div>
```

I tried to write a recursive function but everything messed up. Do I need a recursive function at all ?

Comment: Have you tried using a templating engine?

Comment: Could you provide us with an attempt? Assigning a variable is *not really* coding... You need to provide logic. You mention that you used a recursive function, please show us ;-)

Comment: Do you have control over the structure of the array you are using for data? If so, you can structure myArray differently to make understanding the relationships and rendering the HTML much easier.

Comment: This array comes from a database table. This is the tabular structure. THe first field is the child, the second field is the parent element. I need to convert this table into HTML. It's pretty straightforward to do this manually, but the table is huge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following snippet produces the expected result:

```js
var myArray = [['activity', 'none'] , 
               ['movies', 'activity'],
               ['theater','activity'],
               ['drama', 'movies'],
               ['comedy', 'movies'],    
               ['puppet', 'theater'], 
               ];

var nodes = {};
for (var i in myArray) {
    var child = myArray[i][0];
    var parent = myArray[i][1];
    var children = nodes[parent] || [];
    children.push(child);
    nodes[parent] = children;
}

var divFromNode = function(parent) {
    var div = $("<div id=" + parent + ">");
    var children = nodes[parent];
    div.text(parent);
    for (i in children) {
        var child = children[i];
        div.append(divFromNode(child));
    }
    return div;
}

$("body").append(divFromNode(nodes["none"][0]));
```

```css
div>div {
    margin-left: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I migrated your fiddle to here. I also added CSS because why not? :-p

Answer (score 5):

Instead of an `Element - Parent` relationship, why not try an object?

The following is vanilla JavaScript, no jQuery needed.

**Edit:** I am keeping my original answer in-tact but I you want a more robust solution, check my script at the bottom.

```js
var myObject = {
    'id' : "activity",
    'text' : "activity",
    'children' : [{
        'id' : "movies",
        'text' : "movies",
        'children' : [{
            'id' : "drama",
            'text' : "drama"
        },{
            'id' : "comedy",
            'text' : "comedy"
        }]
    },{
        'id' : "theater",
        'text' : "theater",
        'children' : [{
            'id' : "puppet",
            'text' : "puppet"
        }]
    }]
}
var generateHTML = function(data, targetEle) {
    var node = document.createElement("div");
    if (data.id)   node.setAttribute("id", data.id);
    if (data.text) node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data.text));
    targetEle.appendChild(node);  
    if (data.children) {
        data.children.forEach(function(child, index, siblings) {
            generateHTML(child, node); // Recursion...
        }, this);
    }
}
generateHTML(myObject, document.body);
```

```css
div>div {
    margin-left: 2em;
}
```

---

## Edit

I have created a script to convert the table to an object:

```js
var myArray = [
    ['activity', 'none'] , 
    ['movies', 'activity'],
    ['theater','activity'],
    ['drama', 'movies'],
    ['comedy', 'movies'],    
    ['puppet', 'theater'], 
];
               
var myObject = {
    'id' : "activity",
    'text' : "activity",
    'children' : [{
        'id' : "movies",
        'text' : "movies",
        'children' : [{
            'id' : "drama",
            'text' : "drama"

        },{
            'id' : "comedy",
            'text' : "comedy"
        }]
    },{
        'id' : "theater",
        'text' : "theater",
        'children' : [{
            'id' : "puppet",
            'text' : "puppet"
        }]
    }]
};

var getById = function(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
};

var typeOf = function(obj) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj)
        .replace(/^\[object (.+)\]$/, "$1").toLowerCase();
}

// Converts a relatioship table to an object.
var tableToHierarchy = function(relationMatrix) {
    var generateRelationships = function(matrix) {
        var relationships = {};
        matrix.forEach(function(relationship, index, matrix) {
            var child = relationship[0];
            var parent = relationship[1];
            var children = relationships[parent] || [];
            children.push(child);
            relationships[parent] = children;
        }, this);
        return relationships;
    };
    var generateHierarchy = function(root, relationships) {
        var hierarchy = {};
        var children = relationships[root] || [];
        hierarchy.id = root;
        hierarchy.text = root;
        hierarchy.children = [];
        children.forEach(function(child, index, siblings) {
            hierarchy.children.push(generateHierarchy(child, relationships));
        });
        return hierarchy;
    };
    
    var root = relationMatrix[0][1]; // First record's parent.
    var relationships = generateRelationships(relationMatrix);
    return generateHierarchy(relationships[root], relationships);
};
    
var generateHTML = function(data, targetEle, includeLvl, idPrefix) {
    var generate = function(data, parent, level, prefix) {
        var node = document.createElement("div");
        if (data.id)    node.setAttribute("id", prefix + data.id);
        if (includeLvl) node.className = 'lvl-' + level;
        if (data.text)  node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data.text));
        parent.appendChild(node);  
        if (data.children) {
            data.children.forEach(function(child, index, siblings) {
                generate(child, node, level+1); // Recursion...
            }, this);
        }
        return node;
    };
    switch(typeOf(data)) {
        case 'object':
            return generate(data, targetEle, 0, idPrefix);
        case 'array':
            return generate(tableToHierarchy(data), targetEle, 0, idPrefix);
    }
    return null;
};

generateHTML(myObject, getById('objTest'), true, 'obj_');
generateHTML(myArray,  getById('arrTest'), true, 'arr_');
```

```css
div>div {
    margin-left: 2em;
}

.lvl-0 { color: #ff0000; }
.lvl-1 { color: #00ff00; }
.lvl-2 { color: #0000ff; }
```

```html
<h2>Array</h2>
<div id="arrTest"></div>
<h2>Object</h2>
<div id="objTest"></div>
```

Comment: This is the best solution. +1 @user3191304 you should use this for your educational purposes